# Visual Studio 2017 NodeJS Client-Side Debugging Not Working

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I migrated a small project to VS Code and also created a Visual Studio 2017 solution and project in the same workspace root folder.  They both compile a run just fine together, but I can only get Chrome debugging to work in VS Code (that is, I can enable `All Exceptions` and catch all errors).  In Visual Studio I can run and attach to NodeJS, but unlike ASP.Net debugging with Chrome (where Chrome is launched in a special mode, and both server and client can be debugged side-by-side), NodeJS projects in VS 2017 do not do this.  That is, Chrome is only launched normally (I'm guessing without debugging).

The question is, does NodeJS web projects in VS 2017 support Chrome debugging side-by-side with the NodeJS server (without having to open a second instance of the IDE)? I know there's a command line to run Chrome in debug mode (`chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`, which can be added as a tool in the menu), but I was hoping VS 2017 supports this automatically and I'm just missing something.

Comment: AFAIK, enable script debugging using Chrome in Visual Studio has been enabled in Visual Studio 2017: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/, is that not work for you?

Comment: I already know about that, and yes, it's enabled. Also, that is for ASP.Net projects. The article is not for NodeJS Web projects in VS 2017.